# Remove Hyperlinks using Office Scripts

Tags: excel, vba, office-scripts

i'm kind of a begginer at office scripts and i would like to translate this code from vba that elimante all hyperlinks in a every worksheet in a excel file ( please note that the file is very big and the code needs to be optimised)

VBA code used :

```
sub Removeallhyperlinks()
Dim ws as worksheefor each ws in active workbook.sorksheets
ws.hyperlinks.delete
next ws 
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below. It removes hyperlinks from all of the worksheets in the workbook:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        workbook.getWorksheets().forEach(sh=>{
            sh.getUsedRange()?.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.removeHyperlinks)
        })
    }
```

Comment: yes , it works but is there a way to keep same font as before ?

Comment: I think this may be a bug. This clear method probably shouldn't be changing your font. You can take my code and post another question on StackOverflow and ask if the font change is a bug. If it is, perhaps someone on the Office Scripts team can review and fix. If it isn't, perhaps they can propose a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

```
sub Removeallhyperlinks()
    Dim ws as worksheet
    for each ws in Thisworkbook.worksheets
        ws.hyperlinks.delete
    next ws 
end sub
```

Comment: the vba code that i posted works perfectly , i need to translate it to office scripts so i can automate the process with power automate

Comment: `Dim ws as worksheefor each ws in active workbook.sorksheets`

...right